# Alter Table values using phpMyAdmin, MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am not an expert when it comes to phpMyAdmin. Here's the issue i'm facing:

```
update v_attente_service vas 
join tick4 ti on ti.ticket_id = vas.NOMBATTE
set vas.NOMBATTE = COUNT(ti.ticket_id)
where vas.CODESERV=4
```

I want to display a queue and update the number of people waiting each time a new person prints a ticket. The query above will update the number of people waiting with the count of the tickets.

When i execute the query, i get the following error: "#1111 - Invalid use of group function"

I did find similar questions, and i did try the suggested solutions, however, none of them seem to work. So any help would be very appreciated!

[EDIT]:
Here's the solution that worked for me:

```
UPDATE v_attente_service AS vas 
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(ticket_id) AS cnt FROM tick4) AS ti 
SET vas.NOMBATTE = ti.cnt
WHERE vas.CODESERV=4;
```

I hope this helps others facing a similar issue!

Answer (score 3):

You can check with this query:

```
UPDATE v_attente_service AS vas 
JOIN (SELECT ticket_id,COUNT(ticket_id) AS cnt FROM tick4 GROUP BY ticket_id ) AS ti 
ON ti.ticket_id = vas.NOMBATTE
SET vas.NOMBATTE = ti.cnt
WHERE vas.CODESERV=4;
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much, your query truly helped! However, i did modify it a bit so it would work: UPDATE v_attente_service AS vas 
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(ticket_id) AS cnt FROM tick4) AS ti 
SET vas.NOMBATTE = ti.cnt
WHERE vas.CODESERV=4;